# Can you export package / class information from Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, class, package

I am looking for a way to export or print the class / package structure from Eclipse. I don't need to have a list of the specific functions or variables within these, although that would be nice!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try one of the many UML plugins that are available for eclipse. Some of them can visualize the structure with drag'n'drop, like [**ObjectAid UML Explorer**](http://www.objectaid.com/). Another option I can recommend from personal experience is [**ModelGoon**](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/modelgoon-uml4java).

With these you can define precisely which methods, members and relations you want to see.

Both tools support the export of the generated diagrams as images.

Comment: Do both of these work across languages, or are they only for Java?

Comment: @soulBit both are java only afaik. ObjectAid planned to extend language support at some point but they never did. I'm afraid that for other languages you'll have to use other, external tools or make screenshots of the package explorer view ;)

Comment: Funny you say that, screenshots are exactly how we have been doing it up till now!